# PostGIS: Query using spatial join using pgadmin3

Tags: attribute-joins, postgis-2.3

I have created three tables `ch01.restaurants (SRID 2163;`columns`franchise, geom), ch01.lu_franchises (lookup table, no geom field;`columns`id, franchise), ch01.highways (SRID 2163;`columns`gid, feature, name, state, geom)` in PostGIS that I want to use for a query which includes a spatial join. Running the query in pgadmin3, the following happens:

```
Total query runtime: 32 msec
0 Zeilen geholt.
```

My problem is that the table that will be created doesn't contain any data. I get a table with the heading

```
franchise | total
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT f.franchise, COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) As total 
FROM ch01.restaurants As r 
INNER JOIN ch01.lu_franchises As f ON r.franchise = f.id 
INNER JOIN ch01.highways As h ON ST_DWITHIN(r.geom,h.geom,1609)
GROUP BY f.franchise
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

How can I alter this code so that my result will contain all the franchise restaurants within one mile of a highway?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to indicate what data is contained in the tables. It's very easy to get no rows in a poorly formed join. You should also specify what SRID was used.

Comment: Why do you need `(DISTINCT r.id)`. Else, query is looking good to me. I also suspect some CRS/SRID issue.

Comment: Hello Vince and RoVo, I edited my question and figured out that the geographic data have the same SRID 1609...